# Is it possible to write a reactjs app so that it is easy to use with react-native at a later date?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-native

I want to make a web app which will initially only be used in a browser. However I would like to be able to possibly use this with react-native at a later date if the performance isn't good enough.

I was initially going to use react.js and something like bootstrap, but will this not make it harder to port later on? For instance it seems like react-native is based around flexbox, so should I really be using flexbox from the start?

Comment: Check out the following http://jkaufman.io/react-web-native-codesharing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get a simple one-to-one mapping on react-native/reactjs code, for several reasons but most importantly react-native renders native platform UI components, eg instead of `<Div>` for web react-native would have the `<View>` components https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#content , however a lot of the application logic can be shared, eg, you can use flux and relay in much the same way native and web. Check out this article with presents a workflow for maximising code-reuse across different platforms. http://jkaufman.io/react-web-native-codesharing/